# Office Add-In only loaded as Admin

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js

My Office Add-In (Word, Excel) is only loaded successfully when started the office desktop client (2013, 2016) as Administrator.

When not started as Admin we get this error:
***"ADD-IN ERROR: This Add-In could not be loaded... Close and Click on Reload."***

We face this error in the newest versions of Office 2013 and Office 2016.

[image]

What we have tried:

- Enabled Protected Mode in Internet Explorer
- Deleted Wef directory of Office
- Updated Office versions

*Any ideas why the Add-In could not be started?*

Comment: Is your add-in published to AppSource? Can you share your add-in title?
How are you acquiring the add-in (Sideload, in-client Store, AppSource)?

Comment: It is published via store. The name is IDL.OFFICELINK.

Comment: We can't reproduce this. A member of our team will be in contact to the email address on record to get more information from you so that we can investigate further if required.

Comment: Hi .. I've just spent 5 days ripping my hairs out in frustration that my Outlook Add-in didn't work and displayed the "Add-in error". I'm running Visual Studio as Administrator by default - do you by chance do the same ?

Comment: @Martín Kirk Posted a solution that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is starting as Administrator is no more possible since Visual Studio 16.6.2 - only IIS Express not as Administrator is supported.
Previously we used IIS which only worked when started as Administrator.

In the solution properties of a newly created Office AddIn there are now **multiple startup projects**:
[image]

I tried this in my solution - also switched to IIS Express and used localhost web adress.

We also had to use Action = Start to avoid this error:
[image]

This is not a solution - just a work around - starting as Administrator and using IIS does not work anymore :(
see my [VS Developer Community post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Updated-to-1662---Office-Add-Ins-fail/1082051)